# Reading a tab separated file with Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have encountered a problem reading a tab separated file using Pandas.

All the cell values have double quotations but for some rows, there is an extra double quotation that breaks the whole procedure. For instance:

```
Column A  Column B  Column C
"foo1"    "121654"  "unit"
"foo2"    "1214"    "unit"
"foo3"    "15884""
```

The error I get is: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 31 fields in line 8355, saw 58

The code I used is:

```
csv = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t',  lineterminator='\n', names=None)
```

and it works fine for the rest of the files but not for the ones where this extra double quotation appears.

Comment: but your input data is corrupt then. Wouldn't it be simpler to fix the code which created the buggy file?

Comment: You are right, except this data is from one of our clients. Is there any solution to read this particular file the way it is?

Comment: do you encounter the double quotes only at the end of a line or anywhere?

Comment: The 3-4 cases I've manually checked it happened at the end of a line. Not sure though if that's the pattern as I have a lot of files and large ones as well

Comment: Yep. These files can't be read at all because of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot change the buggy input, the best way would be to read the input file into a `io.StringIO` object, replacing the double quotes, then pass this file-like object to `pd.read` (it supports filenames and file-like objects)

That way you don't have to create a temporary file or to alter the input data.

```
import io

with open(file) as f:
    fileobject = io.StringIO(f.read().replace('""','"'))

csv = pd.read_csv(fileobject, sep='\t',  lineterminator='\n', names=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the preprocessing step to fix the quotation issue:

```
with open(file, 'r') as fp:
    text = fp.read().replace('""', '"')

with open(file, 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(text)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes sense. I'll try it in a bit when I'm back to my computer